# Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start when I try to debug Eclipse JEE web project on local tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, web-applications, eclipse-jee

I have found other stack**overflow** questions similar to this one. The answers seem to be particular to those people's errors, so I gave up on them.

I did not have this error when I left off on this project as I recall. I don't recall changing anything before I came back to this project and got this error.

I want to debug my web app on a local tomcat 8.5 server. In Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers Version 2019-03(4.11.0), I right-click on my web project and select Debug As->Debug on Server. A dialog box appears and I choose the option to Manually define a new server. I select Tomcat v8.5 Server. I click the Finish button. Some red text in the debug window appear. Then a dialog box appears saying:

> 'Starting Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.
>
> Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start.

I have been able to start tomcat with startup.sh successfully, and have been able to shut down tomcat with shutdown.sh successfully, so I know tomcat works by itself.

I am able to run this web project on AWS Beanstalk.

Here is what it says in the debug window:

```
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.41
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 4 2019 09:17:16 UTC
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.41.0
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.14.6
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_211-b12
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/shinehah/eclipse-workspaces/eclipse-java-ee-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/shinehah/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.41
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:56586
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -javaagent:/Users/shinehah/eclipse/jee-2019-03-3/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/402/0/.cp/lib/javaagent-shaded.jar
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/shinehah/eclipse-workspaces/eclipse-java-ee-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/shinehah/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.41
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/shinehah/eclipse-workspaces/eclipse-java-ee-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/shinehah/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.41/endorsed
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/shinehah/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:38 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:38 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1816 ms
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.41
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:39 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webproject10]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:882)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webproject10]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Realm[MemoryRealm]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Memory database file [/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/tomcat-users.xml] cannot be read
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm.startInternal(MemoryRealm.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/tomcat-users.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.file.ConfigFileLoader.getInputStream(ConfigFileLoader.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm.startInternal(MemoryRealm.java:258)
    ... 9 more

Jan 31, 2020 9:54:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:688)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:882)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webproject10]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webproject10]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Realm[MemoryRealm]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Memory database file [/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/tomcat-users.xml] cannot be read
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm.startInternal(MemoryRealm.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/tomcat-users.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.file.ConfigFileLoader.getInputStream(ConfigFileLoader.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm.startInternal(MemoryRealm.java:258)
    ... 9 more

Jan 31, 2020 9:54:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:688)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:882)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webproject10]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webproject10]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Realm[MemoryRealm]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Memory database file [/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/tomcat-users.xml] cannot be read
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm.startInternal(MemoryRealm.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/tomcat-users.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.file.ConfigFileLoader.getInputStream(ConfigFileLoader.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm.startInternal(MemoryRealm.java:258)
    ... 9 more

Jan 31, 2020 9:54:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 31, 2020 9:54:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

In the Problems pane, I see the following 4 errors:

```
Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.1.
JavaServer Faces 2.2 can not be installed : One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
JavaServer Faces 2.2 requires Dynamic Web Module 2.5 or newer.
One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
```

Comment: Is your tomcat embedded tomcat or external tomcat server?

Comment: @Justin I don't know what those mean.

Comment: Did you tried to find file /usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/tomcat-users.xml  ?

Comment: I found tomcat-users.xml, but not in that path.

Comment: Could you please delete the server and reset it, or even re-set the whole project?

Comment: I’ve tried deleting the server and resetting it. How do I reset the whole project without losing OK code?

Comment: I have created a totally new project, but I get the same problem.

Comment: @Justin I was able to create a new server. I get a 404 error when I try to access it, so it looks like it's running. When I run my webapp on it, I get the same error that the server can't start.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to run Tomcat in Eclipse WTP , which is configured in the "Sever Location" section shown below :

[image]

From your log , you should use 1st option now (*i.e. Use workspace metadata (does not modifiy Tomcat installation)*) ,which Eclipse will run Tomcat as [a separate instance](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#How_does_WTP_support_separate_Tomcat_server_instances.3F) which its root folder is located at the configured "server path" (i.e. *$project_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3* in this example ).

Please note that this Tomcat instance is different from what you start tomcat using `startup.sh` from the command line. They have different configuration settings. You should notice that there is a Server project created too after you define a server. This project contains the configuration of this tomcat instance run by Eclipse.

[image]

So open `server.xml` in this Server project and find `MemoryRealm`. I believe you are setting an invalid [`pathname`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/realm.html#Memory_Based_Realm_-_org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm) here which cause this problem. So try to correct it or simply remove it such as it will use the default setting which will refer to the `tomcat-users.xml` in the Server project.

On the other hands , you can try to use 2nd options (*Use Tomcat installation (takes control of Tomcat installation)*). Eclipse will then run Tomcat the same as you run it using `startup.sh` which I believe it should work as you mention it is able to start with `startup.sh`.

Comment: I did a search for "MemoryRealm" in server.xml. That is not found in server.xml.

Comment: Server Locations is grayed out and disabled. How do I change settings in it such as selecting "Use Tomcat installation"?

Comment: Delete the server and then register again. It will allow you to choose for the first time after you just create it.

Comment: That didn't work. Still grayed out. I added content in the post at the bottom. Some errors in the Problems pane.

Comment: not sure , it always work for me. I usually create a server but NOT add any application to it yet ,only add application after select which option to use.

Answer (score 2):

It happens when some Jar files or other dependency related files of your project get corrupted. I was working on a small project when I got the same exception. I removed all the dependencies related to the project and reinstalled them. It started working for me.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I checked a web application in my Eclipse which also run in tomcat 8.5.
The tomcat-users.xml path is [myworkspace]\Servers\Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost-config

Could you please try those steps:

1. download a brand new tomcat8.5 and install into a new folder
2. create a brand new workspace for your project.
3. goto eclipse "Servers" view, click that link to add a server
4. choose Apache tomcat 8.5 in it
5. choose new tomcat install folder
6. add your web application into it
7. right click your newly added server and choose "start"

In those steps, I saw nothing wrong. Could you please try?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean "external"? What do I call what I'm using if not "external"?

Comment: Some IDE or Application (like Spring boot) have embedded web container. But looks like your tomcat is not

Answer (score 0):

Usually developer define the server firstly on the server tab, then run debug on the server

Also I suspect your project type in eclipse is incorrect. I suggest you check the project type.